# Postgres timestamp: what is the number after the dot and how to remove it?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, sql-insert

I'm inserting new records to my Postgres database, using PHP.
In my query i add the function `now()` to write the date and the time of the insert.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myTable(field1, field2, date, field4, field5) values('" . pg_escape_string($value1) . "', '" . (int) pg_escape_string($value2) . "', NOW(), '" . pg_escape_string($value4) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($value5) . "')";
```

The type of the date cell is `timestamp without time zone` and here is how it writes the date:

```
2015-05-26 11:13:51.727018
```

What is that number after the dot and how to avoid it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are microseconds. Define it as `timestamp(0) without time zone` instead.

> `time`, `timestamp`, and `interval` accept an optional precision value `p` which specifies the number of fractional digits retained in the seconds field. By default, there is no explicit bound on precision. The allowed range of `p` is from 0 to 6 for the `timestamp` and `interval` types.

References:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: In the PhpPgAdmin there isn't `timestamp(0) without time zone`... i tried to change it with SQL query but i get a syntax error. Here is my query: `ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN date timestamp(0) without time zone`

Comment: @smartmouse how about `ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN date TYPE timestamp(0) without time zone`?

Comment: You are right! I copied the wrong syntax (`ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype`) from here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Comment: @smartmouse that's another reason to **NEVER EVER** open w3schools

Comment: Are you serious?! O_o

Comment: @smartmouse yep. Not to say I entirely agree with http://www.w3fools.com/ but they have the point.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, it's not a number after the dot, it's part of the number after the last colon: "51.727018 seconds". This doesn't actually have to do with how you *input* the timestamp, but how you *output* it.

See the manual pages for [Date-Time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html) and [formatting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) for how to choose a format that is more suitable for your use, e.g.

```
to_char("date", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

or as an integer Unix timestamp, which saves re-parsing in the application:

```
cast(extract(epoch from "date") as int)
```