# Why selecting a value greater than a certain date also return the matched date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I want to `SELECT` all data AFTER the given date. This is seems simple and basic so I just do it like this:

```
select * from contents where "createdAt" > '2021-10-18 13:27:01';
```

But somehow, the data with createdAt === '2021-10-18 13:27:01' is also selected. And I don't want that. How do I fix it?

**Update:**

This is the `createdAt` column

```
"createdAt" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: Does createdAt include fractions of a second?

Comment: BTW, _timestamp_, not date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare dates in datetime fields in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469154/how-to-compare-dates-in-datetime-fields-in-postgresql)

Comment: @jarlh I'm sorry I don't really understand what is it mean by 'fractions of a seconds' in this context. Can you clear it up?

Comment: Never mind, take a look at Andrea's link instead.

Comment: @AndreaMugnai apparently casting it to date doesn't cast the time (hours, minute and second) so it is just the date and it make it worse for me

Comment: Sounds very strange ... Can you provide an extract of the structure of your table 'contents' (CREATE table contents AS ...) and  with a sample of rows ?

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `where "createdAt" > '2021-10-18 13:27:01.000'`. Unless the timestamp value in the column was exactly that value to the millisecond, this is expected behaviour.

Comment: @Bohemian so how do I ignore the microseconds (I guess), and just compare it until the seconds?

Comment: @EdouardH. I've updated the answer is that what do you mean?

Comment: Change to `>=` and go to the next second: `where "createdAt" >= '2021-10-18 13:27:02'`

Comment: @Bohemian if I set it to `'2021-10-18 13:27:02'` I don't need `>=`. With only `>` is enough since it is how it behave in my case

Comment: You need `>=` to correctly include a timestamp of exactly `'2021-10-18 13:27:02.000`

Comment: @Bohemian okay I'll do that for now, thank you. But I'm curious is there any 'proper' way to do this? This solution seems to be forced and I'm afraid it is prone to miss match

Comment: You can also use the function date_trunc('second', createdAt) so that to ignore the milliseconds in the comparison. In this case, SELECT date_trunc('second', '2021-10-18 13:27:01.005' :: timestamp) > '2021-10-18 13:27:01' :: timestamp returns False as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion, the problem I encountered was caused by `fractions of a second` or microsecond precisions in the [Postgres timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/datatype-datetime.html).

My query is equivalent to `where "createdAt" > '2021-10-18 13:27:01.000'`. And if I have data which `createdAt` value is `'2021-10-18 13:27:01.230'` then of course it will be included in the query result.

**Solutions:**

1. Ignore the microsecond by using `date_trunc` ([more](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date_trunc/)):

```
select * from contents where date_trunc('second', "createdAt") > '2021-10-18 13:27:01'
```

2. Add 1 second.

If you want to select all data after `2021-10-18 13:27:01` then just add 1 second to it:

```
select * from contents where "createdAt" => '2021-10-18 13:27:02';
```

It will compare the "createdAt" value to `=> '2021-10-18 13:27:02.000'` which is `> '2021-10-18 13:27:01'`

I recommend the first solution. The second solution is prone to mismatch the entry, in my opinion. Because we need to process the timestamp before actually executing it. But it still does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite weird, but you can use below query as a way out.

```
select * from contents where "createdAt" >= '2021-10-18 13:27:01'+ INTERVAL '1 ms';
```

This would omit the mentioned Date i.e. '2021-10-18 13:27:01' and get the next available date i.e. which must be 1 ms  greater than the mentioned date.

Comment: based on comments and expected result, you should add 1 second.

Comment: But to avoid mismatch any entry with same seconds but different milliseconds,  this should work as well it is a generic solution  with similar issue.

Comment: apparently the number after dot in postgres timestamp is `microsecond` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454602/postgres-timestamp-what-is-the-number-after-the-dot-and-how-to-remove-it). So ignoring those fraction of second using `date_trunc` does the trick for me. It is weird that I've been working with PostgreSQL quite a long time but somehow I have this problem just now